# Как выбрать минимальное значение из трех таблиц

Tags: mysql

Всем доброго дня! 
В каждой из трех таблиц есть значение price, нужно получить наименьшее в этих трех таблицах, объединенных через JOIN. Получить у каждой по отдельности, проблем нет MIN(). А вот как из всех трех таблиц в одном запросе выбрать наименьшее значение? Если не трудно, черкните пример, пожалуйста

Насколько оптимален запрос такого типа:

```
    SELECT MIN(
      CASE
        WHEN SterlingTradeGross < BlowOutNett
             AND SterlingTradeGross < SterlingTradeQGross
          THEN SterlingTradeGross
        WHEN BlowOutNett < SterlingTradeGross
             AND BlowOutNett < SterlingTradeQGross
          THEN BlowOutNett
        ELSE SterlingTradeQGross
      END
   ) AS LowBid
FROM MyTable
```

если в таблице много записей?

Или есть способ оптимальнее?

Comment: зачем использовать min, если у вас нет группировки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT LEAST(min(t1.price), min(t2.price), min(t3.price)) FROM `t1` join t2 on t1.good=t2.good join t3 on t3.good=t2.good
```

Comment: То что нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: @Tartang отметьте ответ как принятый, плз

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `case`:

```
select o.id, case when o.price<case when t.price>th.price then th.price else t.price end then o.price
else case when t.price>th.price then th.price else t.price end end
from one o
join two t on o.id=t.id
join three th on o.id=th.id
```

[Пример работы](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dab4ca/1)

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w3FQrgA6VC7JtoGzGzkSJi/0, если добавить значения, показывает неверный результат, почему-то... Или я что-то не так делаю

Comment: результат верный, с учетом постановки вопроса. у вас в основной таблице 4 записи, в 2х остальных - по одной. что должно произойти, если цена в других таблицах не указана?

Comment: Наверное изначально нужно было уточнить, мне не важно пересечение по ID, мне просто нужно было выбрать наименьшее значение из всех таблиц... Уже решил. Спасибо за помощь!